# Why am I not getting same output in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I'm not getting the consistent output in two cases:

### Scenario 1:

```
humen = {"hand" => 1, "eye" => 2, "head" => 3, "hair"=>4}
puts  "enter any body part name"
internal = gets.chomp.downcase.to_s

body = humen[internal]

puts body
#if input is "eye", it comes out 2
```

### Scenario 2:

```
humen = {hand:1, eye:2, head:3, hair:4}
puts  "enter any body part name"
internal = gets.chomp.downcase.to_s

body = humen[internal]

puts body
```

I see nothing in irb console. Can anyone please explain why that's the case?

Answer (score 6):

keys are symbol in second case -

```
{:hand=>1, :eye=>2, :head=>3, :hair=>4}
```

whereas `internal` is a *string*. 
`humen[internal]` is expecting the string assigned to internal to be present in hash `humen` which is not the case.

`:hand != 'hand'`

You should convert the string to symbol by:

```
humen[internal.to_sym]
```

[`String#to_sym`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Symbol.html#method-i-to_sym) converts a string into a symbol.